# android studio cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Creating new Android Studio project get the following exception in Gradle build file:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'
```

[image]

Gradle still builds successfully, but still shows this error in editor.

**What's missing from my project?**

Android Studio 3.3.2

Gradle 4.10.1

compileSdkVersion 27

Comment: Android Studio needs to update its default app generator. This happens when you create a new Android application.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Note:** this answer is no longer up-to-date for newer versions of Android Studio and Gradle. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61024577/6296561) instead.

Android Studio seems to have various problems that I cannot understand why exist, but they're fixed by invalidating the caches and restarting (from the file menu item). Because the code compiles fine, it seems that this is one of those cases, in which a cache entry somehow ends up, I'm not really sure what specifically happens, but essentially something that prevents it from working properly.

So invalidating the caches and restarting may issues like this, whether it's with Gradle or with Java/Kotlin/Scala/<insert language here>.

Answer (score 188):

The latest Android SDK does not support `GradleException()`, instead use `FileNotFoundException()`.

Or for future readers, maybe use `RuntimeException` (if the issue is not file related).

I found the issue and the solution on this GitHub thread:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29608

Answer (score 9):

For flutter specific,
It won't throw an error. But if you don't want those **Red letters** then you can replace

```
GradleException
```

with

```
RuntimeException
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is misunderstood by Android Studio, you should not remove `new` section from it because you will build release an error:

```
def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def attribute = new Attribute()
```

No delete `new`