# Flutter Project: Errors

Tags: android, flutter, manifest

All updated information here: [Flutter Project : Errors (mostly with Android Manifest and Main Activity files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391780/flutter-project-errors-mostly-with-android-manifest-and-main-activity-files)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="polacoenchile.world_time_app2">
   <application
        android:label="world_time_app2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is how look my file, I never touch there nothing so I have no idea what is wrong. On the picture i am showing all errors. I make analyze because on emulator all is working good. I made .apk file to install on my phone, i made it but applicacion is not showing nothng, just grey background.
Anyone know what is wrong?

[my app project errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dqKp.png)

[android project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HplU.png)

[android project errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSE3S.png)

[mainactivity file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjl66.png)

MainActivity file

```
package polacoenchile.world_time_app2

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

FLutter doctor found few problems after downgrade flutter to stable version. But i am sure i add plugins to my android studio : Flutter , Dart

```
C:\Users\wdowk>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379], locale pl-PL)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (5 weeks ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\wdowk\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: F:\Program Files\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at F:\Program Files\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: You are opening xml files with android studio from a flutter project? open "android" folder as a separate project (File -> Open -> flutterproject/android) and check if you see any of these errors when your android project builds.

Comment: ok i will try, minwhile, i updated my question, i changed photo because i repaired some. I am newbie with flutter so i have no idea how to check it. i just see that after installation my app doesnt work, i just see grey background like i said and nothing more. So, i will try to make like u said, i hope i undestand how to make it good.

Comment: ok, i made it, i put a screen to my question  above^^ picture number 2 and 3. this is how it look now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391780/flutter-project-errors-mostly-with-android-manifest-and-main-activity-files

Answer (score 0):

You Commented on the part where you shouldn't commented out , If you fix this line all will be working

```
   <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
```

Comment: but look, this comment is closed after, i dont know why here its green but in my app its fine this part

Comment: consider delete the entire android dir and ```flutter create .``` to regenerate a new android  .. by doing this it wont affect your project

Comment: i made it now, i deleted in explorer all android dir, and i wrote this in terminal. now i have again all problems what i had in the begining and i dont have file mainactivity in java but in kotlin now.

Comment: Mind show us what the aftermath of the error ? I mean the current error

Comment: few of them i can repair again, like liocal.properties file by adding / in dir, but still, mostly i have problems with mainactivity files i think, and androidmanifest

Comment: build.gradle i repaired by this: update GradleException() to FileNotFoundException()  i am not sure if is good, i found it in other post. i made it and error gone.

Comment: Oh this one.... You setup flutter wrong and declare it wrong and also the gradle contain some issue which someone answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575122/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-gradleexception

Comment: Yes correct, Now look at te error that says ``windows file seperator``` after you look at it you will know the error immediately

Comment: Sometime wrong setup will cause fail creation of the project. I think after  fix the declaration, the error will gone

Comment: Flutter version ?

Comment: i repaired this what u said, but the rest is still here. like in the pic above

Comment: Repeat the delete and ' flutter create .'

Comment: Flutter (Channel beta, 1.26.0-17.8.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379]

Comment: Just uninstall it and reinstall a stable version man...

Comment: so my flutter is bad? i shpuld change it for other version? which one u suggest? after that my project will be fine ot i will have to change some information in files?

Comment: It is quite bad , because that's not for production I would say.

Comment: i used that flutter channel stable  > flutter upgrade > flutter doctor

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379]

Comment: my mainactivity file look good? i show it now in the question above. i add new screen with error after trying build apk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391780/flutter-project-errors-mostly-with-android-manifest-and-main-activity-files