# After adding google services plugin I found two errors in build.gradle. How to solve this error?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

> ```
> def localProperties = new Properties() def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties') if (localPropertiesFile.exists())
> ```
>
> {
> localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
> localProperties.load(reader)
> } }
>
> def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk') if
> (flutterRoot == null) {
> throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.") }
>
> def flutterVersionCode =
> localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode') if
> (flutterVersionCode == null) {
> flutterVersionCode = '1' }
>
> def flutterVersionName =
> localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName') if
> (flutterVersionName == null) {
> flutterVersionName = '1.0' }
>
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply from:
> "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
>
> android {
> compileSdkVersion 30
>
> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
>     applicationId "com.example.rideapp"
>     minSdkVersion 16
>     targetSdkVersion 30
>     versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
>     versionName flutterVersionName
> }
>
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
>         // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
>         signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> flutter {
> source '../..' } apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

the errors are these
**Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties'**
**Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'**

Comment: This may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575122/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-gradleexception

Comment: I think with errors like this the easiest way is to just remove the whole thing and install it again correctly.